# draw9patch: how to handle non-square images

Tags: android, android-drawable, nine-patch

I have been spending quite some time on looking for an answer for this, but weird enough it does not seem to exist. So I guess the answer is simple, or no-one needs nine patch for these shapes.

[image]

How does one handle draw 9-patching this? Is the only way to supply different sizes and use the different drawable folders and let it scale?
Or is there a way to add a patch on it?

I want to be able to stretch it vertical, but keeping the tip nice...if I would add a patch in the middle at the left side, I expect the tip will get blunt...

Comment: I assume you want to stretch it vertically? Or are you having problems stretching horizontally as well?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if someone has a tip to vertically patch this keeping the tip nice

Answer (score 0):

U can set any image with 9 patch just set layout bounds on their edges which is to be expand

Comment: sorry, my question was not complete I guess...see the part what I added about stretching vertically

Comment: so actually, I should add a patch to the whole left part of the image?